# Как из консоли получить последнее вычисленное значение в интерпретаторе питона?

Tags: python

Запускаю интерпретатор:
 `python`

Потом пишу:

```
10 + 5
>>> 15
```

Я хочу использовать последнее вычисленное выражение `15` в качестве параметра в следующей строчке:

```
(?) * 2
```

B хочу получить на выходе:

```
>>> 30
```

**Вопрос, что нужно написать вместо  `(?)`?**

*Помню можно было как-то это сделать, но не могу найти как.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Символ подчёркивания `_`. То есть, в вашем случае `_ * 2`.